# Changed value of a resource

Tags: android, layout

I'm new to Android. A part of my Activity contains

```
TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_message);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
message.setText(name);
```

`MainActivity` was the previous activity from which the current one was called. Also, the layout file for the above activity is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/show_message" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

</TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/show_message"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:onClick="goBack"
    android:text="Go Back to Activity Lifecycle" />
```

I know that `message.setText(name)` sets the `String` value of `name` to `message` but how come it also changes `show_message`? When the `Activity` starts in the app, it shows the `String` value of `name` where it is supposed to display `show_message`.

Actually, I want the code to perform in the way it is doing right now but I can't understand why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You assigned the key values as MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE

Comment: what's the problem? you are assigning the text of the show_message TV to the value of the extra.

Comment: I knew what the program was doing but didn't know how was it doing so. But I got it now Thanks to Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `String name` isn't being set by `message.setText` rather it's being set by the StringExtra in the received intent (that starts the activity)

`TextView message` is pointing to the `TextView R.id.show_message`

So `message.setText("anything")` would set the text value of show_message to "anything"

`message.setText(name)` sets the text of show_message to whatever String name represents... here the value passed in the intent.